# 3D Line Projection onto a Quad Mesh

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, mesh

I have two 3D points, A and B. These points lie on the surface formed by a quad mesh, M. A and B are not guaranteed to be vertices of the mesh and the line formed between obviously is not guaranteed to lie exactly on the surface.

Lets image one wants to travel from A to B. If we imagine we could project the line onto the surface, I wish to recover the list of faces that projection intersects as we complete the walk from A to B. The line isn't guaranteed to always be inside or outside of the mesh, in fact it could switch from inside to outside or vice versa.

You could think of it as if you were to take a walk along the mesh surface following this line in the "sky" what faces would you visit as you followed the trail from A to B.

I don't need to recover the geodesic distance and I know the line A->B in advance, so it isn't a path finding exercise as such.

How could one go about doing this efficiently?

Comment: I guess you could compute a spatial hierarchy structure for the mesh (e.g. Octree), and query which faces intersect the plane which goes through A, B and the "skyline" you mentioned. To generate the correct sequence of lines for the path you may need a half-edge mesh structure or any other which allows you to query face adjacency

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

The projection is not really defined as long as you don't have a projection direction. Maybe you want a projection which is as orthogonal as possible to the surface ? Maybe a constant direction can do ? (In the latter case, you just need to intersect the surface with a plane.)

You have to find the facets that are close to the line. If you look in the direction of the segment, the faces will appear as line segments and you have to find the segments close to the projected line (seen as a single point).

If you have arranged the facets in a hierarchy of bounding spheres, you can look in any direction, and efficiently find candidate segments (faces). Using the spheres, you can also reject those that do not intersect the (bounded) line in 3D, past the endoints.

Then you can use the faces close to the endpoints to choose a plane direction, and get the individual intersections of the faces with the plane, and reconstruct a 3D polyline.